# Create a color-coded key for a matplotlib scatter plot with specific colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

Here is the data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'letter': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X'], 'color': ['#FF0000', '#FF7F00', '#FFD400', '#FFFF00', '#BFFF00', '#6AFF00', '#00EAFF', '#0095FF', '#0040FF', '#AA00FF', '#FF00AA', '#EDB9B9', '#E7E9B9', '#B9EDE0', '#B9D7ED', '#DCB9ED', '#8F2323', '#8F6A23', '#4F8F23', '#23628F', '#6B238F', '#000000', '#737373', '#CCCCCC'], 'percent': [0.59, 0.569, 0.343, 0.791, 0.099, 0.047, 0.387, 0.232, 0.262, 0.177, 0.522, 0.317, 0.252, 0.617, 0.644, 0.571, 0.382, 0.12, 0.281, 0.855, 0.283, 1.0, 0.844, 0.499], 'score': [0.541, 0.399, 0.625, 0.584, 0.83, 0.859, 0.62, 0.618, 0.545, 0.536, 0.513, 0.563, 0.592, 0.276, 0.037, 0.0, 0.5, 0.653, 0.485, 0.213, 0.44, 0.0, 0.308, 0.35]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head())
  letter    color  percent  score
0      A  #FF0000    0.590  0.541
1      B  #FF7F00    0.569  0.399
2      C  #FFD400    0.343  0.625
3      D  #FFFF00    0.791  0.584
4      E  #BFFF00    0.099  0.830
```

Where the leftmost column is the index.

This code creates a scatter plot:

```py
df.plot.scatter(x='percent', y='score', color=df['color'])
```

[image]

On the right, I want to have a key specifying which color represents which letter. Ideally it should be a list of solid colored rectangles and the letter. I have not been able to find a solution where one can use colors that they had selected, but I need that behavior as there will be multiple plots that need to be color coded the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mpatches.Patch for a custom legend.

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

ax = df.plot.scatter(x='percent', y='score', color=df['color'])

colorlist = zip(df['letter'], df['color'])
handles = [mpatches.Patch(color=colour, label=label) for label, colour in colorlist]
labels = df['letter']

ax.legend(handles, labels, ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

[image: matplotlib result]

Alternatively, you could use seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.scatterplot(x=df['percent'], y=df['score'], palette=df['color'].tolist(), hue=df['letter'])
ax.legend(ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

[image: seaborn result]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.legend` method of the Axes object:

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

ax = df.plot.scatter(x='percent', y='score', color=df['color'])

ax.legend(handles=[mlines.Line2D([], [], color=r['color'], marker='.', linestyle='None',
                                 markersize=9, label=r['letter'])
                   for _, r in df.iterrows()
                  ],
          ncol=3,
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1)
         )
```

[image: custom legend]

*NB. In my opinion, you should not go over ~10 colored items, this strongly impacts readability*

As you have a single element per color, you could annotate the points directly:

```
ax = df.plot.scatter(x='percent', y='score', color=df['color'])

for _, r in df.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(r['letter'], (r['percent'], r['score']), ha='left', va='bottom')
```

[image: scatter plot annotation]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about annotating the points. The names associated with each point in the actual data are actually much longer, but I'll see what my coauthor thinks about using abbreviations.

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth OK, thanks for the feedback. Out of curiosity, why have you chosen the other answer?

Comment: Only because the provided code solves the problem as posed more succinctly. I appreciate your answer as well.